# UIAlertView in iOS 6 Beta 3 (ipad 3) Does not seem to trigger the code in the delegate

Tags: ios, ipad, uialertview, ios6, ipad-3

I ran across this problem where the UIAlertView does not trigger any handlers in the delegate. It works fine on all iOS 5.0 and later/ iOS 6 beta (iPhone4/4s, iPod, ipad1/2) device, but the problem is only with the iOS 6 beta 3 on iPad 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer. This is a little weird, but looks like if you set title of the UIAlertView to nil, it seems to work. I know it sounds weird, but thats how I got it working on iPad3 iOS6 beta 3. when you set a title, it doesn't seem to work. Any better explanations for this? Or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your title is not nil, it crashes because you are invoking it within thread. Call it after main thread gets over. & your problem will be solved. :)